# Delphi XE3 KEY_WRITE not found

Tags: delphi, registry, delphi-xe3

I can't find out where the Registry constants are stored. In the following example, `KEY_WRITE` is not recognised, nor is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` .

And is there any decent help available for XE3 - the 'old' Delphi help was much more helpful!

```
uses System.Win.Registry;
...
...
...
...
reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the `Winapi.Windows` unit to your uses clause:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.Win.Registry;
```

---

The next time you'll be missing a certain symbol, note that you can search for it using your favorite file browser by searching in the `..\Source` directory of your Delphi installation path. If you will refine the search for only `*.pas` files and whole words only, you'll get e.g. for your `KEY_WRITE` symbol 3 files, where this symbol exists:

```
..\Source\data\dsnap\Datasnap.DataBkr.pas
..\Source\rtl\common\System.Win.ComObj.pas
..\Source\rtl\win\Winapi.Windows.pas
```

Then if you open those 3 files and look how the symbol is used there, you'll find, that it's defined in the `Winapi.Windows.pas` file and in the remaining two files is used just in certain function calls.